# Swift Threading with DispatchGroup

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following code, which uses a `DispatchGroup` to get notified when the tasks are done like this:

```
func getSomething(completion: ()->()) {
    completion()
}

func doSomeWork(completion: ()->()) {
    let myGroup: DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        myGroup.enter()
        getSomething {
            myGroup.leave()
        }
    }
    myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { // this here is the key
        completion()
    }
}

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("We are doing background work")
    doSomeWork {
        print("We are done with the work - but on main thread now!!!")
    }
}
```

So the issue I have is that I call some function on a thread, that function has a completion which is called on some fixed queue.

My options are:

1. Detect Thread.isMainThread and either notify on a main queue or background queue
2. Pass the queue we are working on for all function calls
   Issue: This is not really a smart design pattern
3. Deal with the fact that this completion has a fixed queue and then manually dispatch again

But I am not happy with any of the options... I'd rather not have so many dispatches.

Imagine this:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("We are doing background work")
    doSomeWork {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            print("Now we are in background again")
        }
    }
}
```

That is already a level-3 closure and is not really nice to work with especially if in that background async call we have another closure or level.

Any help on what to do here would be great! Thank you

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem you are trying to solve. Cross-thread communication is inherently messy.

Comment: I want to run everything on a background thread, but some functions call a completion handler on the main thread while being called on a background thread. and this creates a lot of switching back and forth.

Comment: Is the issue that the closures are constructed in the main thread and close over that environment, or is it something else?

Comment: The issue is that I‘m calling a function bla({ //block code }) on a background queue. bla() calls the completion handler on the main thread though, due to dispatch groups

Comment: @JanoschHübner why not just use some queue other than main for your notify code to run on?

Comment: well I could but what if I want to run it on main at some point? or a different queue - it is not dynamic but I might do that

Answer (score 3):

> The issue is that I‘m calling a function bla({ //block code }) on a
>   background queue. bla() calls the completion handler on the main
>   thread though, due to dispatch groups – Janosch Hübner

check again your snippet

```
func doSomeWork(completion: ()->()) {
    let myGroup: DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        myGroup.enter()
        getSomething {
            myGroup.leave()
        }
    }
    myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { // this here is the key
        completion()
    }
}
```

and see, that because `getSomething` is synchronous you could simply write

```
func doSomeWork(completion: ()->()) {
    //let myGroup: DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        //myGroup.enter()
        getSomething {
            //myGroup.leave()
        }
    }
    //myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { // this here is the key
        completion()
    //}
}
```

In case `getSomething` should be asynchronous, use the proper API to run it within some group

```
func doSomeWork(completion: ()->()) {
    let myGroup: DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        //myGroup.enter()
        queue.async(group: myGroup) {
            getSomething {
            //myGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
    myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { // this here is the key
        completion()
    }
}
```

Running `completion()` on the same thread (it is better to say on the same queue) as `doSomeWork(completion: ()->())` is simple.

```
func doSomeWork(completion: ()->()) {
    let myGroup: DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        //myGroup.enter()
        queue.async(group: myGroup) {
            getSomething {
            //myGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
    //myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { // this here is the key
        myGroup.wait()
        completion()
    //}
}
```

check next playground page and see how DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform could change your design and how goup notification works

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Dispatch

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let q0 = DispatchQueue.global()
let q1 = DispatchQueue(label: "my_queue", attributes: .concurrent)
let g = DispatchGroup()
let g1 = DispatchGroup()
q0.async(group: g) {
    print("1    message from \(q0): will do some concurrent jobs in the background")
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 5, execute: { (i) in
        sleep(1)
        print("\t",i)
    })
    print("2    message from \(q0): all concurrent jobs done")
    q0.async(group: g) {
        print("3    some other long time running on group...")
        sleep(3)
        print("3 ex")
    }
    q0.async(group: g1) {
        print("?    some other long time running on gifferent group...")
        sleep(4)
        print("? ex")
    }
    g1.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
        print("g1 empty")
    })
}
print("4    continue on main")
g.notify(queue: q1) {
    print("5    message from \(q1): finished a")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        sleep(1)
        print("6    from main, should stop playground execution?")
        //PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
    }
    print("7    message from \(q1): finished b")

}
g1.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("8    from main, g1 is empty.")

}
print(" ... continue")
```

which prints on my environment

```
1    message from <OS_dispatch_queue_global: com.apple.root.default-qos>: will do some concurrent jobs in the background
4    continue on main
 ... continue
8    from main, g1 is empty.
     0
     2
     1
     3
     4
2    message from <OS_dispatch_queue_global: com.apple.root.default-qos>: all concurrent jobs done
3    some other long time running on group...
?    some other long time running on gifferent group...
3 ex
5    message from <OS_dispatch_queue_concurrent: my_queue>: finished a
7    message from <OS_dispatch_queue_concurrent: my_queue>: finished b
6    from main, should stop playground execution?
? ex
g1 empty
```

Comment: myGroup.wait() would block the queue‘s work again wouldn‘t it?

Comment: it blocks the queue where doSomeWork is executed. you could execute it asynchronously ... if needed

Comment: @user3441734 In your block #4 you say that we could just use 

```queue.async(group: myGroup) {
            getSomething {}
```

However this would not work, if getSomething inside is async and goes to another queue, it would not handle the group enter/leave correctly and finish too early

Comment: @MarcoPappalardo if getSomething {} is internally async, what is the idea to call it asynchronously? Anyway in such a case commented myGroup.leave() is call immediatly, with the same result.

Comment: @user3441734 for example `getSomething` is a network layer.
You want to start many network requests in parallel and wait for all of them to finish to notify.

the completion block of the `getSomething` is executed only when the request finishes. so the calls are needed. 

What I am saying is that the group.leave() is mandatory for it to work in your example where you say "it's async"